# How do i select range of data in Treemap Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, treemap

How can i select range of data to be plotted in Highcharts treemap?
 Currently it is plotting all the data points and since there are large number of data points and most of them has value ranging from -100 to 200. but i want it to plot for the range between 500 to 1000.

Comment: If you want to add only part of your data, why you don't want to preprocess it before you will load it into your chart? http://jsfiddle.net/zr5dzzkd/ It this example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: i want to make range of data selectable via UI

Comment: So you want to achieve something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/zr5dzzkd/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess your data before you will load it into your chart. You can use input text forms for getting the range you want to display in your chart:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var from = parseInt($('.from')[0].value),
      to = parseInt($('.to')[0].value),
      newData = [];
    if (!isNaN(from) && !isNaN(to)) {
      Highcharts.each(data, function(p) {
        if (p.value >= from && p.value <= to) {
          newData.push(p);
        }
      });

      $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
          type: 'treemap',
          data: $.extend(true, [], newData)
        }],
      });
    }
  });
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/zr5dzzkd/1/

Comment: Blachlinski : This is the solution i am looking for but since i am using Highcharts treemap in R so i am not able to reproduce the equivalent of this function. Is there any way i can use this function in R ?